# How to verify the Scala binaries?

Tags: scala, executable, digital-signature, verification

I have searched everywhere and I have not found the checksums for verifying the integrity of the Scala binaries nor any certificate or signature for verifying the author. Any ideas on how to verify the Scala binaries downloaded from the official website?

Comment: Why not use a package manager? It does this stuff for you.

Comment: open issue on this: https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/issues/188 . note that most people use JARs from Maven Central, rather than using the distribution packages.